# Expected primary-expression before ‘*’ token

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have written a code to find max element in a binary search tree, I am getting the following error in Insert function:

> main.cpp: In function ‘bstNode* Insert(bstNode*, int)’:
>
> main.cpp:23:31: error: expected primary-expression before ‘*’ token
>
> root->left= Insert(bstNode* left,data);
>
> ^
>
> main.cpp:25:32: error: expected primary-expression before ‘*’ token
>
> root->right= Insert(bstNode* right,data);
>
> ^

Following is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct bstNode{
  int data;
  bstNode* left;
  bstNode* right;
};

bstNode* GetNewNode(int data){
  bstNode* newNode=new bstNode();
  newNode->data=data;
  newNode->right=newNode->left=NULL;
  return newNode;
}

bstNode* Insert(bstNode* root,int data){
  if(root==NULL)
    root=GetNewNode(data);
  else if(data <= root->data)
    root->left= Insert(bstNode* left,data);
  else
    root->right= Insert(bstNode* right,data);
  return root;
}

void FindMax(bstNode* root){
  if(root->right==NULL)
    cout<<root->data;
  else
    FindMax(root->right);
}


int main()
{
  bstNode* root=NULL;
  int T;
  cin>>T;
  int i,data;
  for(i=0;i<T;i++){
    cin>>data;
    root=Insert(root,data);
  }
  FindMax(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Please tell me what is the error and how can I rectify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass the type `bstNode *` in `root->left= Insert(bstNode* left,data);` and the other similar line with `right`.

Did you mean to write something like `root->left= Insert(root->left,data);` instead?

Comment: Yes, that's working. Thanks a lot. I am sorry for asking such silly questions, I am new to Data Structure and recently started to study trees.

Comment: @shardul08 the problem has nothing to do with data structures or trees, you need to review the chapter on functions ;)